# error: no visible @interface for 'NSObject' declares the selector 'copyWithZone:'

Tags: ios, copywithzone

I want to allow deep copy of my class object and am trying to implement copyWithZone but the call to `[super copyWithZone:zone]` yields the error:

```
error: no visible @interface for 'NSObject' declares the selector 'copyWithZone:'

@interface MyCustomClass : NSObject

@end

@implementation MyCustomClass

- (id)copyWithZone:(NSZone *)zone
{
    // The following produces an error
    MyCustomClass *result = [super copyWithZone:zone];

    // copying data
    return result;
}
@end
```

How should I create a deep copy of this class?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You should add the `NSCopying` protocol to your class's interface.

```
@interface MyCustomClass : NSObject <NSCopying>
```

Then the method should be:

```
- (id)copyWithZone:(NSZone *)zone {
    MyCustomClass *result = [[[self class] allocWithZone:zone] init];

    // If your class has any properties then do
    result.someProperty = self.someProperty;

    return result;
}
```

`NSObject` doesn't conform to the `NSCopying` protocol. This is why you can't call `super copyWithZone:`.

Edit: Based on Roger's comment, I have updated the first line of code in the `copyWithZone:` method. But based on other comments, the zone can safely be ignored.

Comment: This is correct.  I wrote out a similar answer but he beat me  :)

Comment: Your answer completely ignores the zone.  See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9907154/

Comment: @RogerBinns See the accepted answer to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4631526/iphone-idcopywithzonenszone-zone-what-is-zone-for?rq=1